# Merge two JSON arrays and then sort them

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

How would I merge both JSON `arrays` and then sort the value of ID so that the result displays the highest number to the lowest number?

For example, my desired output from the script below would be:

- 1 - Jimbo
- 2 - Bob
- 6 - Luke
- 12 - Chris
- 16 - Jonas
- 36 - Sam

Here's my JSON arrays:

```
$json1 ='
{
    "error": "trueee",
    "info": {
        "collections": [{
            "ID": "1"
            "Name": "Jimbo"
        }, {
            "ID": "36"
            "Name": "Sam"
        }, {
            "ID": "2",
            "Name": "Bob"
        }]
    }
}
';

$json2 ='
{
    "error": "trueee",
    "info": {
        "collections": [{
            "ID": "12"
            "Name": "Chris"
        }, {
            "ID": "6"
            "Name": "Luke"
        }, {
            "ID": "16"
            "Name": "Jonas"
        }]
    }
}
';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `merge` the arrays from the json string. First json decode for getting the arr with associative array than get the columns of `ID` using `array_column`, after that you need to merge the two array and finally sort them.

[Online Check](https://3v4l.org/hgavr) and a [Long Conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112951/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-the-codesee)

```
$json1 ='
{
    "error": "trueee",
    "info": {
        "collections": [{
            "ID": "1"
        }, {
            "ID": "36"
        }, {
            "ID": "2"
        }]
    }
}
';

$json2 ='
{
    "error": "trueee",
    "info": {
        "collections": [{
            "ID": "12"
        }, {
            "ID": "6"
        }, {
            "ID": "16"
        }]
    }
}
';

$arr1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$arr2 = json_decode($json2, true);

$arr1 = array_column($arr1['info']['collections'], "ID");
$arr2 = array_column($arr2['info']['collections'], "ID");

$arr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
sort($arr);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 12
    [4] => 16
    [5] => 36
)
```

Comment: I make my answer from the json string, Did the loop needed for some validation checking?

Comment: If you can explain some about the loop than i can hep you better ways.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112951/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-the-codesee).